# How to prevent left/right arrow from cycling through completion candidates on the :cmdline?

Tags: neovim

Say I have 4 files in current directory:

```
file-bar-01.txt
file-bar-02.txt
file-foo-01.txt
file-foo-02.txt
```

Next, I want to save current buffer to a new file `file-foo-03.txt`. So I enter `:w f` and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> for a few times until the cmdline becomes `:w file-foo-01.txt`:

[image]

Then, I want to use <kbd>←</kbd> to move cursor to `1` and change it to `3`. But if I press <kbd>←</kbd> it'll behave like <kbd>Shift-Tab</kbd> and the previous file `file-bar-02.txt` is selected and the cmdline becomes `:w file-bar-02.txt`:

[image]

So how can I ask <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> to move cursor rather than cycle through the file completion candidates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in `:help wildmenu`:

> While the menu is active these keys have special meanings:
>
> - <kbd>CTRL-Y</kbd> - accept the currently selected match and stop completion.
> - <kbd>CTRL-E</kbd> - end completion, go back to what was there before selecting a match.
> - <kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd> - select previous/next match (like <kbd>CTRL-P</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL-N</kbd>)
> - <kbd>Down</kbd> - in filename/menu name completion: move into a subdirectory or submenu.
> - <kbd>CR</kbd> - in menu completion, when the cursor is just after a dot: move into a submenu.
> - <kbd>Up</kbd> - in filename/menu name completion: move up into parent directory or parent menu.
>
> **If you want** <kbd>Left</kbd> **and** <kbd>Right</kbd> **to move the cursor instead of selecting a different match**, use this:
>
> ```
>   :cnoremap <Left>  <Space><BS><Left>
>   :cnoremap <Right> <Space><BS><Right>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd> (as a mnemotechnic reminder I think of it as Ctrl-"Yes" to validate the selection)

When you use <kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd> in a selection menu it chooses the selection but does not launch the command line

After the filename that pleases you most is selected/validated, you can now edit the filename using <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> and change it to your taste